# Assigning a variable to a variable via raw_input?

Tags: python, logic

I am trying to get input from a user into a variable but instead of a string, float or integer I want it to assign a different variable which is already defined. Pseudo-ish example:

```
xy = 23
a = raw_input("Enter a variable") xy
print (a)
23
```

Yes, this could be controlled with an if variable but for many variables this is not very practical I believe? I have no problem typing it just wondering wouldn't it be bad practice?

Comment: I'm so confused.  You want to set the value before you request it?  You don't need to request it?  You need to set one value and then set another one, but they need to be the same?  What are you trying to _accomplish_?

Comment: @g.d.d.c Let me fix up the code example Im really struggling to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
xy = 23
a = eval(raw_input("Enter a variable"))
print (a)
```

The task of adding a check in case the user enters an unkown variable is left to the reader...

Also beware of the potential security problems of this approach. A more secure way would be to restrict the evaluation scope by defining specific `dict`s that `eval` should be using. Read more in `help(eval)`.

Comment: Using `raw_input` with `eval` is pretty much equivalent to just using `input` (and has the same security risks)

Comment: @mgibsonbr The example above is exactly what I was looking for however Im not exactly sure what you guys mean by security risks?

Comment: @DraganMarjanovic It is a security risk because the user may input any code they like and it will be executed, for example a user could input `__import('os')__.system("rm -rf /*")`. If this is a program you will only ever use then it's not a problem, but always take into consideration that use of eval on anything related to user input can lead to major problems.

Comment: @Anorov Ah yeah Ive done this on some php pages yeah I see how it could be a problem just wasnt considering it for other use but defintely handy to see what you meant should look into eval more Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `globals()` to get a dict with all the variables in the global namespace, or `locals()` for the local namespace:

```
>>> xy = 23
>>> a = globals()[raw_input("Enter a variable ")]
Enter a variable xy
>>> print (a)
23
>>> globals()
{'a': 23, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None
, 'xy': 23, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

[More info](http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html) about them. At top-level, both will return the same dict, but the difference can be seen when used inside a function:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...   print globals()
...   print locals()
...
>>> foo(10)
{'a': 23, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None
, 'xy': 23, '__name__': '__main__', 'foo': <function foo at 0x00BC5FB0>, '__doc_
_': None}
{'x': 10}
```

Note that this technique does not involve `eval` in any way, so if an user attempts to enter a malicious input it will just raise a `keyError`. However, depending on what you plan to do with the variable, there might be some security risks nonetheless (in this sense, using `locals()` is safer, since you can control over the precise set of variables that can be accessed this way).

Comment: yeah This is definitely great and I will probably use it sometime but eval is easier in the application Im using. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just hold your var's in a dict, it's also probably the safest:

```
In [52]: d={'x':1,'y':2,'z':3}

In [53]: a=d.get(raw_input('enter var'),None)
```

Example:

```
In [57]: a=d.get(raw_input('enter var: '),None)

enter var: y

In [58]: print a
2

In [59]: a=d.get(raw_input('enter var: '),None) # You can specify a default value

enter var: Foo

In [60]: print a
None
```